# JWT token work, but it fail on next day when I visit the page

Tags: jwt, express-jwt

I am new to JWT. Using "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.0",

In my web application, I have success use JWT to do the authentication. 
I can log in, create a valid token in the local storage. There is no problem to using it for data gathering from server.

But there is an error when I visit the page on next day.

In my code, I set it expiredIn: '30d'. So, I do not need to keep to sign in each time I visit the website. Everything works, token works.
local storage contains data in json format.

```
{
    token: long token string,
    user: { username: user }
}
```

Next day, I come back. The website does not ask me to sign in, but it has an error on the console, error show up, **username undefined**. I have to sign out and log in again. Then I get a new token to work. but it crashes again on next day.

Which step am I missing?

```
const crypto = require('crypto').randomBytes(256).toString('hex');
config.secret = crypto;
const token = jwt.sign({userId: user._id }, config.secret, { expiresIn: '30d' });
```

[JWT.io debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SK4q.png)

It shows token from 4/11 expire in 5/11

Comment: Can you show us the token, or at least the exakt value of exp (after decoding on jwt.io)?

Comment: I have updated the image and source code I use for produce token. 
  
  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI1YWNkNDU0M2I4ZWNiMjAwMTQ4NGY5NjYiLCJpYXQiOjE1MjM0NzQ0MTYsImV4cCI6MTUyNjA2NjQxNn0.isZHvmGBwHc_V83lAEHPL-kncZ1boAGGrzlAEZv1D9M

Comment: Your token have an `exp` (exipration) claim set at 1526066416 (e.i. 2018-05-11T19:20:16+00:00).
You have to renew it. You can test using https://jwt.io/

Comment: So, I have to do renew when I reopen the website? Is it done on the server side or angular cli side? or I have to do it on both?